# Testing API:GET localhost:3000/api/locations/_id: => loads for a longtime, returns nothing

Tags: javascript, rest, callback, mean-stack

I'm currently learning MEAN stack using this book called *getting-MEAN* by Simon Holmes, and I came across an issue, the book said the request mentioned in the title should return a response, that **should be a full location object**, stored in my MongoDB.

yet it just loads for a long time and outputs this [Postman output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWRpf.png)
I'm thinking, I've messed up my enviroment versions since the book uses an older enviroment?

My environment:

> ✗ uname -srmo
>   Linux 4.11.6-3-ARCH x86_64 GNU/Linux
>   ✗ node --version
>   v8.1.2
>   ✗ express --version
>   4.15.0
>   ✗ mongod --version
>   db version v3.4.3
>   git version: f07437fb5a6cca07c10bafa78365456eb1d6d5e1
>   OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
>   allocator: tcmalloc
>   modules: none
>   build environment:
>      distarch: x86_64
>     target_arch: x86_64
>    ✗ npm list mongoose
>    loc8r@0.0.1 /home/username/github/Loc8r
>      └── mongoose@3.8.40

#### Loc8r/app_api/controllers/location.js

```js
var mongoose = require ('mongoose');
var Loc = mongoose.model ('Location');

var sendJsonResponse = function (res, status, content){
    res.status (status);
    res.json (content);
};

module.exports.locationsCreate = function (req, res) {
    sendJsonResponse (res, 200, {"status" : "Create success"});
};

module.exports.locationsListByDistance = function (req, res) { 
    sendJsonResponse (res, 200, {"status" : "ListByDist success"});
}; 

module.exports.locationsReadOne = function (req, res) {
    Loc
 .findById (req.params.locationid)
 .exec (function (err, location){
     sendJsonResponse (res, 200, location);
 });

}; 

module.exports.locationsUpdateOne = function (req, res) { 
    sendJsonResponse (res, 200, {"status" : "success"});

}; 

module.exports.locationsDeleteOne = function (req, res) { 
    sendJsonResponse (res, 200, {"status" : "success"});
};
```

#### Loc8r/app_api/routes/index.js

```js
var express = require ('express');
var router = express.Router ();
var ctrlLocations = require ('../controllers/locations');
var ctrlReviews = require ('../controllers/reviews');

//locations
router.get ('/locations', ctrlLocations.locationsListByDistance);
router.post ('/locations', ctrlLocations.locationsCreate);
router.get ('/locations/:locationid', ctrlLocations.locationsReadOne);
router.put ('/locations/:locationid', ctrlLocations.locationsUpdateOne);
router.delete ('/locations/:locationid', ctrlLocations.locationsDeleteOne);


//reviews
router.post ('/locations/:locationid/reviews', ctrlReviews.reviewsCreate);
router.get ('locations/:locationid/reviews/:reviewid', ctrlReviews.reviewsReadOne);
router.put ('/locations/:locationid/reviews/:reviewid', ctrlReviews.reviewsUpdateOne);
router.delete ('/locations/:locationid/reviews/:reviewid', ctrlReviews.reviewsDeleteOne);

module.exports = router;
```

#### Loc8r/app_api/models/db.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var gracefulShutdown;
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/Loc8r';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    console.log ("NODE ENVIROMENT: "+ process.env.NODE_ENV);
    dbURI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
}

mongoose.connect(dbURI);

// CONNECTION EVENTS
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
    console.log('Mongoose connected to ' + dbURI);
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Mongoose connection error: ' + err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function() {
    console.log('Mongoose disconnected');
});

// CAPTURE APP TERMINATION / RESTART EVENTS
// To be called when process is restarted or terminated
gracefulShutdown = function(msg, callback) {
    mongoose.connection.close(function() {
        console.log('Mongoose disconnected through ' + msg);
        callback();
    });
};
// For nodemon restarts
process.once('SIGUSR2', function() {
    gracefulShutdown('nodemon restart', function() {
        process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2');
    });
});
// For app termination
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    gracefulShutdown('app termination', function() {
        process.exit(0);
    });
});
// For Heroku app termination
process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
    gracefulShutdown('Heroku app termination', function() {
        process.exit(0);
    });
});

// BRING IN YOUR SCHEMAS & MODELS
require('./locations');
```

#### Loc8r/app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('./app_api/models/db');

var routes = require('./app_server/routes/index');
var routesApi = require ('./app_api/routes/index');
// var users = require('./app_server/routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app_server', 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// tells the application to check the server application routes
// for all incoming requests
app.use('/', routes);
app.use ('/api', routesApi);
// app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

#### Loc8r/app_api/models/location.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

...

...

var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: String,
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        "default": 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5
    },
    facilities: [String],
    // Always store coordinates longitude, latitude order.
    coords: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2dsphere'
    },
    openingTimes: [openingTimeSchema],
    reviews: [reviewSchema]
});

mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);
```

[Mongoshell:test query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj2mf.png)

It should return the JSON object in the Mongoshell test query, when I request GET localhost:3000/api/locations/594d96ab87e3602861443e1e

Answer (score 0):

Your `findById()` function may be failing. Have you tried logging the `err` variable to see if it is throwing an error?

```
Loc
    .findById (req.params.locationid)
    .exec (function (err, location){
        if(err) console.log("err", err)
        sendJsonResponse (res, 200, location);
    });
```

Comment: I added the code, it is doing the same thing as before. I'm clueless as to why this error exist, although I noticed the request: GET localhost:3000/api/locations/1234 should have a response {"status" : "success"}, in my case it returns blank

Comment: You could try replace `if(err) console.log("err", err)` with `if(err) res.send({error: err})` so that your express server doesn't keep hanging and actually returns something (providing an error is thrown)

Comment: I see, that did something although not to the request GET localhost:3000/api/locations/_id: ,its still doing the same thing as before, but something happened to the request GET localhost:3000/api/locations/1234 it now returns JSON object {
    "error": {
        "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"1234\" at path \"_id\"",
        "name": "CastError",
        "type": "ObjectId",
        "value": "1234",
        "path": "_id"
    }
}

Comment: What's the difference between those two endpoints? Aren't you replacing `_id` with a location ID i.e. `1234`? Which would make those requests the same right?

Comment: yes the first one,../1234 returns an error because it's not valid. But the request with an existing ObjectId is just loading forever, that's why you said findById() is failing, I wonder if I'm missing something in my schema such as a  _id: Type:Object? The book said that is not needed. I few people have this same problem, but there is no definitive solution for it.